# Removing the double quotes from a string

Tags: vb.net

I have a variable `images` that is a String. The value of the `images` are in this format:
`"['C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\RiceLAB\BLB01.JPG';'C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\RiceLAB\BLB02.JPG']"`

How can I convert the value of the `images` to something without the double quotes in the beginning and ending (or should I change the String into some other types of variables? The format that I want is this:

`['C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\RiceLAB\BLB01.JPG';'C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\RiceLAB\BLB02.JPG']`

**No double quotes**

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this...

```
Dim s as String = "['C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\RiceLAB\BLB01.JPG';'C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\RiceLAB\BLB02.JPG']"
s = s.Replace("'", "").Trim()
```

Any character or word or phrase or even a sentence is considered a string when it's enclosed in double quotes, but if the value of your string literally has double quotes, like this "SAMPLE", and you want to remove the double quotes, then do something...

```
Dim s as String = ""['C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\RiceLAB\BLB01.JPG';'C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\RiceLAB\BLB02.JPG']""
s = s.Replace("""", "").Trim()
```

Yes I noticed...double double quotes...I equated s to something that you say is passed from MATLAB, the string literally has double quotes, so to remove this, you replace double double quotes with nothing. That's how you do it in .NET. Your compiler interprets double double quotes as just a single quote :)

Comment: I'm still getting an error. As you can see in this picture http://imageshack.com/a/img691/8201/bdaq.jpg , there are still double quotes in the beginning and ending. By the way, I'm passing the `images` variable to a function that I made in MATLAB that's why the value of the `image` should be like this
`['C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\RiceLAB\BLB01.JPG';'C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\RiceLAB\BLB02.JPG']`

Comment: tried it but it doesn't work. My MATLAB function is still reading it as `"['C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\RiceLAB\BLB01.JPG';'C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\RiceLAB\BLB02.JPG']"`

my matlab function should read it like this (without the quotes)
`['C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\RiceLAB\BLB01.JPG';'C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\RiceLAB\BLB02.JPG']`

Comment: I don't think MATLAB is reading that as you say it is. It's always showing the double quotes because it's a string. But I could be wrong, anyways, try putting the picture file in the root directory of C:, it might be the space between Elvin Gentiles, it's unlikely, but if you don't know where the error is, might as well try everything, so do it like this... C:\BLB02.JPG

Comment: I'm still getting an error and again it's because of the double quotes due to the variable being a String. Is there a way how can I convert the String data type to another type? What I mean is that it will retain it's format like this `['C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\RiceLAB\BLB01.JPG';'C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\RiceLAB\BLB02.JPG']` but not as a string

Comment: There is no other way unfortunately, a directory location should and must be a string. Okay try this... before passing the string to MATLAB, messagebox the whole string and paste what the string is here, I'll verify what's in it.

Comment: I do have a question. If you're passing a directory location string to MATLAB, why are you having [' and '] enclosing the location string? Try removing this to pass purely the location string.

Comment: actually I did that so that I can pass an array of locations in matlab. My actual problem is how can I pass the OpenFileDialog.FileNames to MATLAB so that my MATLAB can read it as an array of strings. But I cannot figure it out that's why I'm trying this method

Comment: There are a number of ways to communicate with MATLAB, COM and an API, I'm not sure if there are more but I'm sure of the 2. If you're importing a MATLAB DLL, most likely you're on the API route. Check this out... It might help you... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6e3e3e10-2e09-4317-ae99-5f05260af103/tranfer-an-aray-from-matlab-to-vbnet

Answer (score 8):

The String class has a `Replace` method that will do that.

```
Dim clean as String
clean = images.Replace("""", "")
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error. As you can see in this picture http://imageshack.com/a/img691/8201/bdaq.jpg , there are still double quotes in the beginning and ending. By the way, I'm passing the `images` variable to a function that I made in MATLAB that's why the value of the `image` should be like this
`['C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\RiceLAB\BLB01.JPG';'C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\RiceLAB\BLB02.JPG']`

Comment: What is the error message? Are you getting the error when replacing the string or error is coming from the function in MATLAB? Have you checked the output of the code above? Debug it. What is the value of clean veriable in the code above. I would suggest you to look for the problem in your function that you are passing the images veriable to.

Comment: can you read my comments below? I already posted the error there. Thanks

Comment: Pass the clean veriable in the code above, to your MATLAB function

Comment: I already did that but my Matlab cannot read it because my MATLAB is reading the double quotes at the beginning and ending

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:  (Line had a double quote that I didn't want)

Line = Line.Replace(ChrW(34), "").Trim()

Answer (score 0):

Based on the OP's comments I think there is some confusion. Maybe you are new to .Net, coming from MATLAB.
To re-iterate in VB or C# .Net this is an Empty string:

`""`

that is a string with length == 0. That is something distinct from a string with the value of a quote or double quote.

To continue:

```
Dim singleQuoteString As String = "'"
Dim doubleQuoteString As String = """"
```

and so, what you are asking for

```
['C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\RiceLAB\BLB01.JPG';'C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\RiceLAB\BLB02.JPG']
```

is not a string.

Now, if you want a Textbox, , console output, or something else to show that value then just take your string, like

```
Dim listOfImagesAsAString = "['C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\RiceLAB\BLB01.JPG';'C:\Users\Elvin Gentiles\Desktop\RiceLAB\BLB02.JPG']"
```

and assign it to where you want it, like

```
Console.Write(listOfImagesAsAString)
```

then the command prompt will show what you are asking for.